# How can i retrieve the values from weak entity in spring using hibernate?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, jsp

**POJO class**

```java
public class Professor {
    private long id;
    private String department;
    String imagepath;
    private List<String> subjects; 

    public List<String> getSubjects() {
        return subjects;
    }

    public void setSubjects(List<String> subjects) {
        this.subjects = subjects;
    }
}
```

**Controller**

```
List<Professor> list= pdao.getProfessorById(id);

            for(Professor p : list){
                String courses = String.join(",", p.getSubjects());
               out.println(courses);
            }
mv=new ModelAndView("profdetails","professors",list);
```

**JSP**

```
 <c:forEach var="professor" items="${professors}">
             <c:out value="${professor.getId()}" />
             <c:out value="${professor.getFirstName()}" />
             <c:out value="${professor.getLastName()}" />
             <c:out value="${professor.getSubjects()}" />

 </c:forEach>
```

I need to display subjects List of a professor on a JSP page.
My professor class has 'subjects' as a weak entity defined in hbm.xml file. Iam getting LAzyInitializationException

Comment: and is there any error or you are not sure how to set subjects to professors?

Comment: I strongly recommend against using `hbm.xml`; I haven't seen it used in real code in 10 years. Everything is annotation-based now.

Comment: @HemantKUMAR i have set subjects to the professor. One to many association. I am not sure how to retrieve the values from subjects table. I am getting LazyInitializationException

Comment: @chrylis-onstrike- I know but the req says we have use hbm.xml